# How to parse attribute values from XML with ORACLE

Tags: xml, oracle

Here I have a code that extracts rates from an XML :

```
with tbl as
(
    select
        XMLType(
        '<exchange_rates>
            <rate units="1" code="AUD">2.6</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="THB">0.1</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="BRL">0.9</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="BGN">2.2</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="CAD">2.9</rate>
            <rate units="100" code="CLP">0.5</rate>
        </exchange_rates>'
        ) xml
    from
        t_temp
)
select
    extractValue(value(t), 'rate') result
from
    tbl t,
    table(XMLSequence(t.xml.extract('//rate'))) t;
```

The result for this code is

```
RESULT
------
2.6
0.9
2.2
2.9
0.5
```

It's OK but I'd like to get also attribute values and get a result like this:

```
Units Code RESULT
----- ---- ------
    1 AUD  2.6
    1 BRL  0.9
    1 BGN  2.2
    1 CAD  2.9
  100 CLP  0.5
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's XML functions take XPath expressions, so you'd use the @*attributename* syntax to identify attributes.  Also, you can use the `XMLTABLE` function to make the structure a bit easier/clearer.

```
with tbl as
(
    select
        XMLType(
        '<exchange_rates>
            <rate units="1" code="AUD">2.6</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="THB">0.1</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="BRL">0.9</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="BGN">2.2</rate>
            <rate units="1" code="CAD">2.9</rate>
            <rate units="100" code="CLP">0.5</rate>
        </exchange_rates>'
        ) xmldata
    from
        dual
)
select units, code, rate
from   tbl,
       xmltable('/exchange_rates/rate' 
                      PASSING tbl.xmldata 
                      COLUMNS rate NUMBER PATH '.', 
                              code VARCHAR2(3) PATH './@code', 
                              units NUMBER PATH './@units');
```

> ```
> +-------+------+------+
> | UNITS | CODE | RATE |
> +-------+------+------+
> |     1 | AUD  |  2.6 |
> |     1 | THB  |  0.1 |
> |     1 | BRL  |  0.9 |
> |     1 | BGN  |  2.2 |
> |     1 | CAD  |  2.9 |
> |   100 | CLP  |  0.5 |
> +-------+------+------+
> ```

Comment: As well as `XMLTABLE` being clearer and easier to work with, `EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` have been deprecated since (IIRC) 11g!